# How can make my c# messenger works on the internet not only on the local networks?

Tags: c#, networking

I'm working on a simple c# messenger and its works on the local network only. Does somebody know what should i do to make it works on the internet?

The solution contains the server project that listening on a certain port, and a client project connect to the server with that port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clients need to be able to communicate with the server, which means that either:

1. You need to host the server application on a computer that is directly connected to the internet.
2. You need to setup port forwarding on the router that controls internet access for your network.

In either case the clients will need to know the IP address to connect to, and any firewall interactions need to be considered.  This may also include ISP firewalls, as some ISPs limit inbound connections to subscriber connections.

I won't go into the specifics of setting up port forwarding on a router... there are plenty of examples, and every router is different.  Google will help you with this if necessary.

Ideally you should have a static IP address for this, or some method for the clients to locate the IP address that your server is hosted on.  If you must run from a dynamic IP address (such as some ISPs still use for subscribers) then one of the Dynamic DNS options might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In-order to make it work on Internet a simple answer is you need to enable ports which is used for communication.Generally the ports will be blocked by the Companies firewall for security reasons.So contact your IT dept to enable the port.
Or Use common port like 80.